# Merging branches into master that have changed the same file

Tags: git, merge

**Context:**

I am working on a project where we follow this workflow:

- Create branch for feature
- Make code changes as necessary
- `git commit` back changes
- `Git push` back to feature branch

Then

- Someone reviews the code
- Merges the branch into `master`.

---

**Question:**

I've created 2 different branches that both mess with the same file - essentially I've re-written the whole file in 2 different(yet unmerged) branches.

How would GIT behave in this scenario?

Comment: https://git-scm.herokuapp.com/docs/git-merge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git will try to merge the changes automatically, if it can, it will.  If there is a conflict, git will mark the lines with issues and they must be manually edited.

Comment: ty, just what I expected

Answer (score 1):

Merge will cause conflicts and you will have to fix them.